# Django HttpResponseNotModified method

Tags: python, django

In django, how does use `HttpResponseNotModified` return a response that do nothing about current page?
Some error occurs when I link to this url:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('views',
    url(r'speed/$', "Speed", name='speed'),
)

def Speed(request):
     return HttpResponseNotModified()# ????
```

In request `GET` method, it is `<QueryDict: {u'speed': [u'1'], u'id': [u'777c6c1c-4959-4497-83b0-67f8b4c1ce81']}>`

The error message:

```
'QueryDict' object is not callable
```

What should `HttpResponseNotModified` use if I want to return a response that do nothing about 
curren page ? Thank you .

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "do nothing about current page"? Also, `request.GET('id')` should probably be `request.GET['id']` (as also indicated by the error you're getting), but I still cannot understand what exactly you're trying to accomplish with this code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling `request.GET` which is not a method nor a callable object.

```
return HttpResponseNotModified(request.GET('id'), )# ????
#                                         ^    ^
```

You should use `request.GET['id']` or `request.GET.get('id')`, ...

But, according to [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotModified), `HttpResponseNotModified` does not take any arguments:

> The constructor **doesn’t take any arguments** and no content should be
>   added to this response. Use this to designate that a page hasn’t been
>   modified since the user’s last request (status code 304).

So the return statement should be:

```
return HttpResponseNotModified()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have modified the code by using `return HttpResponseNotModified() `. But the error message says `'QueryDict' object is not callable`.

Comment: @changzhi, Check whether the code have `request.GET('..')` other place in the view. And replace that with `request.GET.get('..')`, or remove it unless you use it.

Answer (score 0):

request.GET is a QueryDict. You access its items like you would a normal dictionary:

```
request.GET['id']
```